# Executar chamada no retrofit 2

Tags: android, api, retrofit

estou com problemas para criar a chamada com o retrofit 2 para a seguinte url:
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/2310?api_key=MINHA_API_KEY&language=pt-BR

No android, a chamada que estou fazendo está retornando um erro, não sei se é por causa do modelo estar errado ou se estou fazendo o GET incorreto:

```
@GET("movie/{id}?")
fun getMovie(@Path("id") id: String,
             @Query("apiKey") apiKey: String,
                 @Query("language") lang : String = "pt-BR" ): Call<Movie>
```

Poderiam me ajudar a descobrir se o GET que montei está necessáriamente se transformando na url que citei no inicio? Se sim, partirei para a analise do model

Answer (score 0):

Cara, eu tive um problema parecido uma vez, acho que a falha está na aqui `@Query("apiKey") apiKey: String`. Creio que deveria ser `@Query("api_key") apiKey: String`.